# Issue with Column Width in IText 7 Tables

Tags: itext, itext7

I have the following table created with fixed column width as follows,

```
 Table headerTable = new Table(new float[]{5,5,5});
 headerTable.setWidthPercent(100);

 headerTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Student Name : Michel John(xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx)")).setFontSize(10).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
 headerTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Admission Date : 2012-05-01")).setFontSize(10).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
 headerTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Current Standard : Eigth Standard - 'B' Section")).setFontSize(10).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
```

But when I see the output format in my PDF file , the column width is uneven.
[image]

Am I missing something in that code snippet ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest version of `iText` - 7.1.x line - and use the code below to create a table with columns of even width:

```
Table headerTable = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{5,5,5}));
headerTable.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
```

Comment: This does not work for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

To fix column width we can use `setFixedLayout()`, in iText7. And it worked for me

```
    Table content = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{3,5,10}));
    content.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
    content.setFixedLayout();
```

Comment: It workes for me, tks.

Comment: iText7.2.5: I noticed that giving the col width as PercentArray and define the table width as 100%, the setFixedLayout() call is no more needed, as shown in Alexey Subach answer.